# Making SOAP client on Unity but getting SOAP exception

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, soap, soap-client

I am making SOAP client on unity for .net web service, but I am receiving an Access denied error i.e.

> SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> Authentication to host '104.130.222.145' for user 'tapblueapp' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'tapblueapp'@'showoff-new' (using password: YES) ---> Access denied for user 'tapblueapp'@'showoff-new' (using password: YES)

I have generated proxy class for the service by name **SampleService.cs**. And calling GetModelOption() by creating an instance of the partial class **WebService**(which is in SampleService.cs) which invokes GetModelOption operation.

The back-end is connected to database which returns data against the request. 
I have followed http://gyanendushekhar.com/2017/02/18/call-asp-net-web-service-unity3d-asmx-service/
to create proxy class.

My code for calling the service is :

```
        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "ip:port");
        CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
        myCache.Add(new System.Uri("http://builderapi.showoff.com/WebService.asmx"), "Negotiate", credential);
        WebService webService = new WebService();
        webService.Credentials = myCache;
        webService.GetModelOption();
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the back end is throwing an exception that it can't connect to the db.  I think this soap exception is actually generated by the back end not by unity.  Try testing it in Postman.

Comment: i tried on Postman and this is the response :


`Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. `